# Pasar valores de una jTable de un JFrame a una Clase en JAVA

Tags: java, jtable

estoy tratando de enviar los valores de un JTable de un JFrame a una clase, ya que en esa clase usare esta informacion para poder llevarlo a un .pdf

pero resulta que nose como tomar(en el JFRAME) y como recibir(en la Clase) la tabla.

en el JFrame llevo unos valores de text:

```
 import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

  llamaalpdf pdf=new llamaalpdf();  

    pdf.crear_PDF(TITULO.getText(), AUTOR.getText(), ASUNTO.getText(), CLAVE.getText(), TEXTO.getText(),jTable1.getModel());
}
```

el jTable1 estoy tomandolo de esa manera, y en la clase llamaalpdf necesito recibirlo:

```
public void crear_PDF(String t, String a, String s, String k, String c,/*aca deberia tomar la tabla*/){
}
```

ya que despues tomare fila por fila he intentare guardarlo un pdf.habra alguna manera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues hay dos formas que se me ocurren, una sería enviando todo el JTable y la segunda enviando solo el contenido, la cual se me hace mas viable ya que desempaquetaras el contenido igualmente.
Puedes crear una función que te devuelva el contenido de tu tabla a un arreglo bidimensional por ejemplo:

```
        public String[][] obtenerContenido(JTable tabla){
//El tamaño de tu arreglo lo defines con el numero de filas y columnas
            String[][] aux = new String[tabla.getRowCount()][tabla.getColumnCount()];
            for (int i = 0; i < tabla.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < tabla.getRowCount(); j++) {
                    aux[i][j] = (String) tabla.getModel().getValueAt(i, j);
                }
            }
            return aux;
        }
```

Así ya solo añades al constructor de tu procedimiento el String[][]:

```
public void crear_PDF(String t, String a, String s, String k, String c, String[][] arreglo){
}
```

Saludos